# Spring Security - call secured method from local

Tags: spring, security, annotations

on a Spring Security service layer I have a method `createUser()` with annotation `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")`. This already works.

But when installing this application, the first user must be created. Currently I am trying to create a default user on startup when the user database is empty. Later this should be done via web interface. But what is the best approach for something like this? Currently I can not create the first user because I am no admin. I could secure the method in the web controller, but securing the service layer is a better approach I think.

Do I need something like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')") OR DATABASE IS EMPTY
```

or is it possible to call a local method with an authority?

I would assume this problem is already solved 100 times :-)

Best regards,
Jochen

Comment: If you create database using Flyway or Liquibase, you can also insert sql scripts for some data initialization, for instance user-roles, first-user etc.